# What's the equivalent of the deprecated GRANT ALL on SQL-Azure?

Tags: azure-sql-database

Apparently, when I execute:

```
grant all to myself;
```

I get the error message telling me that *grant all* is deprecated on SQL Azure. After googling for a while, I haven't found an equivalent. Is there any? Or is one required to specify all the rights explicitly now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you use schemas (which you should) there is a grant control option which is equivalent to grant all
see [books online - grant statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187940.aspx)

```
grant control on schema :: foo
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all deprecated means it still works, for now.
To answer your question, grant all should be replaced with the explicit permissions (EXECUTE/READ/...)

Comment: Actually, the message says that it **doesn't do** what's expected, so I'm afraid that the change's already in effect. But I can live with explicit specification of all rights. It's just quite many to keep track of.